# How to interpret python cProfile output

Tags: python-3.x, performance-testing, pulp, cprofile, snakeviz

I am running cProfile on my python script in order to see where i can improve performance and using snakeviz to visualize. The results are pretty vague however; how do I interpret them? Here are the first few lines of it:

```
 Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   242059    0.626    0.000    0.914    0.000 pulp.py:585(__init__)
        1    0.413    0.413    0.413    0.413 {built-in method _winapi.WaitForSingleObject}
343978/302    0.293    0.000    0.557    0.002 pulp.py:750(addInPlace)
  4159617    0.288    0.000    0.288    0.000 pulp.py:165(__hash__)
      112    0.282    0.003    0.282    0.003 {method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
  1913398    0.172    0.000    0.245    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        1    0.171    0.171    0.185    0.185 Betfair_Run_Sheet.pyx:243(betfairFinalArray)
   377866    0.168    0.000    0.293    0.000 pulp.py:637(addterm)
     2255    0.161    0.000    0.161    0.000 mps_lp.py:249(<listcomp>)
        1    0.148    0.148    0.570    0.570 mps_lp.py:174(writeMPS)
   117214    0.139    0.000    0.444    0.000 pulp.py:820(__mul__)
        2    0.136    0.068    0.196    0.098 pulp.py:1465(variablesDict)
        5    0.135    0.027    0.135    0.027 {method 'do_handshake' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
      427    0.111    0.000    0.129    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:914(get_data)
       71    0.108    0.002    0.108    0.002 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
     2093    0.102    0.000    0.102    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
```

I am using Pulp so aware that takes the lion's share of the time, but the specifics of the setup is not clear from the above, e.g. for the first line of output it seems to be alluding to a line 585 in my script but that is not where I have called or set up the PULP part in it at all.

Same with the `<listcomp>` 9th one down, there is no list comprehension on that line of my script.

Other things like `{method 'do_handshake' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}` I don't have a clue what they mean.

Comment: `pulp.py:585` is line 585 in the `pulp.py` file, not your script. The MPS stuff is also part of Pulp.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.